# Ensuring immutability when generating a map object

Tags: javascript

I have read countless articles on immutability in JS and I am still confused on the following code.

Would it be correct to use `map.set` in the loop in order to add items to the map object, or would it be correct to use the spread operator and spread the previous map into a new map on each iteration in order to ensure immutability?

```
const list = [
  {
    id: 'dog',
    label: 'Dog',
  },
  {
    id: 'cat',
    label: 'Cat',
  },
  {
    id: 'horse',
    label: 'Horse',
  },
]

const thing = function generateThing(id) {
  return {
    id,
    build() {
      return true
    },
  }
}

const map = new Map()
```

**Option 1**

```
for (let i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i += 1) {
  const { id } = list[i]
  map.set(id, thing(list[i]))
}
```

**Option 2**

```
let map = new Map()

for (let i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i += 1) {
  const { id } = list[i]
  map = new Map([
    ...map,
    [id, thing(list[i])],
  ])
}
```

Comment: It would be correct to use `map.set`; copying the entire map for every insertion is hugely inefficient. Some of the immutability dogma that’s gotten into JavaScript lately is really stupid, so be careful. (If you want to write this the immutable way, it’s with `list.map` anyway.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of those two, `map.set()` is definitely the better way. Consider also using a `for`/`of` if the environment you’re targeting has iterator support (which also avoids unnecessary destructuring):

```
const map = new Map();

for (const item of list) {
    map.set(item.id, item);
}
```

So clear! You can create the same map without mutating it like this:

```
const map = new Map(
    list.map(item => [item.id, item])
);
```

but you should pick the one that you find more readable, not the one that you can call immutable because it sounds good. Local state is a perfectly good way to approach a problem, especially in a language like JavaScript that wasn’t specifically designed to be functional.